# In which class(model or controller or view class) mouse event handling method should present

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I just want to know which class (model , controller or view class) should contain mouse event handling methods .

for example drawrect method should present in a view class .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mouse event handling should be in the view class.  Other classes do not receive mouse events — if you add a mouse event handler somewhere else, it will not be called.